# PHP - Loading CSS using cookie, but cookie isn't being read?

Tags: php, css, cookies

I currently have a web site where users can select a custom theme.  After they choose the theme, a cookie is created.  The cookie contains the correct data and points to the correct CSS file.  For some reason, upon re-visiting the site, the theme is not loaded.  I should point out that I am new to PHP so it may be a very easy mistake.  Please help.  Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$stylesArr = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
if(isset($_GET['theme']) && in_array($_GET['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
    $style = 'CSS/' . $_GET['theme'] . '.css';
    setcookie("theme", $style, time()+(60*60*24*30));
} else {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['theme']) && in_array($_COOKIE['theme'], $stylesArr)) {
        $style = 'CSS/' . $_COOKIE['theme'] . '.css';
    } else {
        $style = 'CSS/Default.css';
    }
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style>" type="text/css"media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are putting a string `CSS/Default.css` into a cookie, but then you are checking against string `Default` from `$stylesArr`. Change this line:

```
$style = 'CSS/' . $_GET['theme'] . '.css';
```

to this:

```
$style = $_GET['theme'];
```

and it will be okay.

Also, I must warn you about using data directly from $_GET in your application. You should never do that, because it can lead to severe security problems. Always sanitise user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the $path parameter in your `setcookie()` call.  If you don't set it, it defaults to the current directory.  In this case, you want the cookie to be sitewide, so try this:

```
setcookie("theme", $style, time()+(60*60*24*30), '/');
```

You also need to be sure that the `setcookie()` call occurs *before* any other output.  If you have this in your page below some HTML or any other output (including whitespace or anything not between `<?php ?>` tags), then `setcookie()` won't work.

Comment: Ok, I just tried what you said and also made sure the PHP code was at the top, but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you've already called [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start) right at the start of your script.

Comment: He's using his own cookie not the session cookie. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, but I would write that code more like this:

```
define('MONTH_IN_SECONDS', 2592000);
$themes = array('Default', 'Black', 'Pink', 'Green', 'Red');
$theme = reset($themes); //first value is default
if (isset($_GET['theme']) && in_array($_GET['theme'], $themes, true)) {
    $theme = $_GET['theme'];
    setcookie("theme", $theme, time()+ MONTH_IN_SECONDS);
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['theme']) && in_array($_COOKIE['theme'], $themes, true)) {
    $theme = $_COOKIE['theme'];
}
$themeURL = 'CSS/' . $theme . '.css';
```